# detect if element is between two equal elements in python list

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list with some elements. I need to detect if one of the elements is between two another equal elements.

e.g., if I have list like below:

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 9, 4]
```

I need to determine both element 5, 7, 8 between two elements 4 and element 9 between elements 4. Distance between same elements can be ANY lenghts. I have no elements "To find" and "Between". I need to check if ANY element is between ANY other equal elements:

```
print("you have one element 5 between elements 4 in list")
```

Comment: What about the 1?

Comment: would `4,3,5,3,4` count? What have you tried?

Comment: Are all your elements integers?

Comment: 1. I don't care about 1-s, because they are one after another and there are not other elements between them

Comment: can you use numpy?

Comment: 2. Yes, 4,3,5,3,4 is count. But firstly I need detect at least one case

Comment: 3. No, there are not only integers in list. So, I think numpy can't help

Comment: Is the value of the surrounding items given, or can they just need to be any item or type, as long as they are equal?

Comment: So the item does not have to be directly between two adjacent items?  - YES

Comment: they just need to be any item or type, as long as they are equal - YES

Comment: Your question is too broad, read [ask].

Comment: neighbouring elements don't have to be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 4, 9, 4]

repeats = [e for e in set(data) if data.count(e) >= 2]

for edge in repeats:
    left, right = data.index(edge) + 1, len(data) - data[::-1].index(edge)
    betweens = data[left:right]
    others = set(betweens) - {edge}
    if not others:
        continue
    for e in others:
        c = betweens.count(e)
        if c == 1:
            print(f"you have one element {e} between elements {edge} in list")
        else:
            print(f"you have {c} element {e} between elements {edge} in list")
```

Output:

```
you have one element 8 between elements 4 in list
you have one element 9 between elements 4 in list
you have one element 5 between elements 4 in list
you have 2 element 7 between elements 4 in list
```

Comment: Again, I have no any elements to find or between. I need to check if ANY element is between ANY other equal elements in list

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
lst = [1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4]

x=[[lst[i], lst[i+1]] for i in range(len(lst)-2) if lst[i] == lst[i+2] and lst[i] != lst[i+1]]
```

and as an output you will get list of [a,b]
where
a - element surrounding
b - element surrounded

Comment: dear down-voter - what's precisely wrong with my answer ?

Comment: "Yes, 4,3,5,3,4 is count"